# Is there any mathematical model of how does rain & other weather conditions impact the radio link?

Tags: radio-frequency, radio

I'm looking through UAV radio-communication process and wondering if there are any formulas, describing how does the air pressure and weather itself (rainy & snowy conditions) affect the radiolink between the base station and the actual plane flying on the specific altitude.

Comment: You mean like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_fade ?

Comment: @JonCuster, kinda yes, but that don't actually describe how each kind of density of the rainfall affects the radio channel. There is some abstract data provided on this link

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3081171/ is a good read. Air pressure will not have a large impact, the issue is scattering, and the result will depend on your wavelength and specifics of the rain/snow (size of the scattering objects is important, and rain drops aren't the same size in different storms).

Comment: @JonCuster, thanks, will have a look!